# is there a way to display a message for views if there are no results?

Tags: views

I am using user relationships and activity feed, which displays actions from a existing view.  If no view exists, it means either they have no friends or their friends have no activity so is there a way to have a message displayed for no results?

Comment: You should add information about the version you are using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In "Basic settings," there's a field called "Empty Text" that is displayed if there are no results.

If you're using arguments, you can set "Display empty text" if the argument is not present.

Answer (score 13):

For Drupal 7 / Views 3 the answer would be:

Check the "Advanced" Options on the right side. There you can add a "NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR".